# asp.net mvc core 2 select value is always 0 in view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a select in a view that always returns 0 to my view model, and I don't know why:

**View Model:**

```
// CreateLifeInsuranceViewModel.cs
using InsuranceListManager.Models.EntityFrameworkModels;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace InsuranceListManager.Models.ViewModels.Home
{
    public class CreateLifeInsuranceViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int CustomerId;

        public IList<CustomerModel> Customers { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string InsuredPersonCPF { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController
{
    public IActionResult CreateLifeInsurance()
    {
        var customers = (
            from c in _db.Customers select c    
        ).ToList();

        var model = new CreateLifeInsuranceViewModel
        {
            Customers = customers
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateLifeInsurance(CreateLifeInsuranceViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var category = _db.InsuranceCategories.Where(c => c.Id == InsuranceCategoryModel.LIFE_INSURANCE).First();

            var insurance = new InsuranceModel
            {
                CategoryId = category.Id,
                CustomerId = model.CustomerId
            };

            _db.Add(insurance);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            var lifeInsurance = new LifeModel
            {
                InsuranceId = insurance.Id,
                InsuredPersonCPF = model.InsuredPersonCPF
            };

            _db.Add(lifeInsurance);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model InsuranceListManager.Models.ViewModels.Home.CreateLifeInsuranceViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New Insurance";
}

<h1>New Insurance</h1>

<hr />
<form asp-action="CreateLifeInsurance">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label asp-for="CustomerId">Customer</label>
            <select class="form-control" asp-for="CustomerId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Customers, "Id", "Name"))">
                <option value="">Select the customer</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label asp-for="InsuredPersonCPF">Insured Person CPF</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="InsuredPersonCPF" placeholder="CPF" />
            <span asp-validation-for="InsuredPersonCPF" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a class="btn" asp-action="Index">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

in the rendered HTML, the select has the correct values, as you can see in the screeshot:

[image]

But for some reason, the value that I receive from this select in the view model is always zero:

[image]

Also, the asp validation won't catch if I don't select any item from the select.

I've been researching this for the last 4 hours and found not a single similar issue around.

I am using Asp.Net MVC Core 2, .Net Core SDK 2.2, Windows 10 Pro and Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the value `0` because that is the default value of `int`.

When the form is submitted, the default model binder will try to read the form data and assign the values to the corresponding **properties** of the view model object. Model binder will be able to successfully do so if `CustomerId` is a **property** and the property is **set**table.

In the code you shared, you are not creating a property but a field. Hence the model binder cannot set the value for that.

To fix the problem, change the `CustomerId` property to be **set**table by specifying the `set` and `get` property accessors.

```
[Required]
public int CustomerId { set; get; }
```

Comment: its not exactly about "property being settable" but the fact that it needs to be a property while he has used a field. you are not wrong, just the terminology

Comment: It has to be a property with `set` property accessor for model binder to set the value. `public int CustomerId {  get; }` will not work even though it a property.

Comment: Agreed. It is surely worth mentioning that the property needs to be set as well. I was just mentioning, we can't call his refer to his `CustomerId` field as a "property without set".

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that i forgot to edit Bind attribute (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.bindattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) that was left there when I scafollded my controllers.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,BenchmarkScore,PicturePath,Price")] PcComponentItemVM componentVM)
    }
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the name attribute to the element:

```html
<select class="form-control" asp-for="CustomerId" name="Model.Customers.CustomerId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Customers, "Id", "Name"))">
    <option value="">Select the customer</option>
</select>
```